# Determine my network card?

Tags: windows, drivers, ethernet

I've got a fresh install of Windows, but I just noticed that my ethernet card will not work. Checking the device manager, it appears as "Ethernet Controller" and is missing a driver. Is there any way to detect what device it is and what driver I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Device Manager`, right-click on the network adapter and select `Properties`.

Go to the `Details` tab.

Select the `Hardware Ids` property.

You should see something like `PCI\VEN_####&DEV_####&...`.

Take that ID after the `DEV_` and use the [PCI Database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/index.php) to search for the device.  There is a link for a driver download for 99% of the hardware I've ever had to search for on there.

Comment: I've now installed the driver, and all seems to have gone well. I'll attempt to plug it in now.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and have been quite frustrated. I've also been able to install drivers for the other unknown devices.

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the Start Button and then click the "Programs" folder.
2. Next, click the "Accessories" and then the "System Information" folder.
3. Within the System Information window, click the + symbol next to Components.
4. Click the "+" next to "Network" and highlight "Adapter", in the right side of the window you should be able to locate complete information about the network card.

---

1. Another method of determining the network card in the computer is by physically looking at the network card. Many times the network card will list the manufacturer and part number on the actual card.
2. If you are unable to locate a manufacturer or model number of the network card, but are able to locate a FCC identification number, it is recommended that you perform a FCC search using that number. Additional information about FCC numbers and how to search for information about a FCC number can be found on our FCC dictionary definition page.

Comment: Your first suggestion doesn't return a Vendor or Device ID that will allow you to search for drivers.